# How to get event webhook when email get fired through sendgrid portal

Tags: php, sendgrid

We are sending mails through marketing campaign.
I want to get the event from each lead
I am using sendgrid portal to send mails.

So I want to know the API or PHP code to connect with Sendgrid portal to fetch event data

Comment: This should help https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event

Comment: @Haridarshan  I referred that but it is not fully understandable to me

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I believe you need to [setup the event webhook in your SendGrid console](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/mail_settings) (see under Event Settings). You can use the settings panel to test your webhook integration before it goes to production too.

Check out this [documentation on getting started with the event webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook) for more information.